# Deleting CSS Rule does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to delete the first css rule.

However, this does not work in Firefox 3.6.28. Is this the same for everyone and why is this the case?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(window).load(function(){

                console.log(document.styleSheets);
                document.styleSheets[0].deleteRule(0);
                console.log(document.styleSheets); // same as the first console.log

            });

        </script>
        <style>
            body{font-size:62.5%;}
            #mc{padding:310px 0 10px 162px; color:#fff;}
            #content{width:500px;}
            #header{padding-top:10px;}
            #banner{padding:10px 0}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        Test JS
    </body>
</html>
```

### Update

Just to clarify, the delete seems to be working however the `console.log` shows the same number of rules before and after the delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to work just fine for me

example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/JmWwM/

you need to check the length of the `cssRules` property.

If you log the actual object in firebug then when you try to dig deeper it will show you the current state of the stylesheet, so it will have a reduced number of rules.. (*since by the time you start digging the deletion will have occured*)

but if you log the actual number of rules before and after the deletion then it will show the correct results..

so the problem is a mistake in understanding how the `console.log` command works.

Comment: Yup, works for me, too, on Firefox 3.6.15, Chrome 18, and Firefox 12 (and Opera 11): http://jsbin.com/uhonek I, too, was initially confused by Chrome's dev tools doing the same thing with the dig-down behavior

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you the `console.log` explanation.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule `stylesheet.deleteRule(index)` , delete rule accepts an index so your `1` should be a `0`.

I created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N3zsw/.  I had to make some changes to your code since there are other stylesheets on the page so 0 == 3.

It appears to work for me.  When you do `console.log` you should be displaying `console.log(document.styleSheets[0])` instead of `console.log(document.styleSheets)`. The CSS

Comment: I made a mistake there. Regardless, the number of CSS rules are equal before and after the deletion in the `document.styleSheets` object. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
        <style>
            body{font-size:62.5%;}
            #mc{padding:310px 0 10px 162px; color:#fff;}
            #content{width:500px;}
            #header{padding-top:10px;}
            #banner{padding:10px 0}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function () {
                var s = document.styleSheets[0];
                console.log(s.cssRules.length);
                s.deleteRule(1);
                console.log(s.cssRules.length);
                s.deleteRule(1);
                console.log(s.cssRules.length);
                s.deleteRule(1);
                console.log(s.cssRules.length);
                s.deleteRule(1);
                console.log(s.cssRules.length);
            })();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Test JS
    </body>
</html>
```

it is working fine, i think its about firebug's object reference thing